Jenkins withcredentials
I have a script which contains git clone, however I saved the credentials using jenkins UI under jenkins credentials so whenever I check out normally I use withcredential, so how can I run the script that contains git clone in this case?
I tried to use withcredentials and then running the script inside it but it gives me permission denied
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'test', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEYFILE', passphraseVariable: '', usernameVariable: 'SSH_USERNAME')]) {
                            sh 'git clone ssh://bitbucket.test.com:4444/test/test'

and the output

Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
exists.


Edit your question, add your code, add the error message

This syntax has been working for me. The credentials are stored in the Jenkins Global Credential store, whereas the GIT_CREDENTIAL_ID is the ID defined by yourself, the GIT_USERNAME is x-token-auth and GIT_PASSWORD is the access token.
  steps {
    dir('project_dir') {
      script {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'GIT_CREDENTIAL_ID', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD')]) {
          bat '''
          git clone [...]
          '''
        }
      }
    }
  }


I edited my question, could you please help?
